# Replace text between two symbol Sing through regex

Tags: java, regex

I am not good with regex and trying to achieve the below scenario

```
String s="Example$for$string%is%notworking";
```

Now I need to replace the String between the symbol sign with other string

```
Examplewithstringarenotworking
```

I am using now

```
s=s.replaceall("\\$(.*?)\\%", "bird");
```

but no changes have happened with the above expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
 String s="Example$for$string%is%notworking";
 s.replaceAll("[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]", "otherstring")
```

But in above approach we do not consider many of the special characters like some of DOS smilies like [little angle](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f47c/index.htm)  and [white smily face](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm)

So may need to try some thing opposite. which are characters you want to keep. some thing as below , i am taking A-Z, a-z and 0-9 as below:

```
s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "otherstring")
```

Comment: It is not replacing the text value between two sign instead it is appending the new string in the sign position's